# How to customize the tool tip of GOOGLE MAP (KML) with JAK API

Tags: google-maps, jak

I have a problem with the tool tip in google map.

As you can to see, I have one polygon in my map. But when I click on this polygon as you see in the kml display, the display of the tooltip is cut (Click on the zone map).

To realized this map, I used a KML file, the KML is generated with JAK API.

I think it should be possible to modify the css of the tool tip with the api but I don't know how. I already searched a couple of hours.

I m not an expert with this API and Google Map. So If you have any advice to resovle this problem don't hesitate. I'm going to continue to search.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

You'll find below a set of image that explains the problem :

[image]
[image]

URL To test a KML File :

http://display-kml.appspot.com/

Content of the KML File :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Document>
        <name>IBR</name>
        <Style>
            <PolyStyle id="toolTip">
                <color>0xb9cbf1</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle id="lineStyle">
                <color>0x666ef8</color>
                <width>1.0</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>           
        <Placemark>
            <name>Edmonton Yp</name>
            <styleUrl>#toolTip</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>-113.99345397949219,53.65755844116211 -113.98419189453125,53.59413146972656 -113.93543243408203,53.42497253417969 -113.68433380126953,53.25069046020508 -113.68347930908203,53.250675201416016 -113.67694091796875,53.250667572021484 -113.39179992675781,53.25058364868164 -113.3207778930664,53.25060272216797 -112.96499633789062,53.39612579345703 -112.87796020507812,53.45442199707031 -112.80402374267578,53.51348114013672 -112.80384826660156,53.54147720336914 -112.80400848388672,53.57035827636719 -112.95169067382812,53.65762710571289 -113.29582214355469,53.71658706665039 -113.56759643554688,53.720455169677734 -113.93214416503906,53.71586608886719 -113.93550872802734,53.715370178222656 -113.99345397949219,53.65755844116211</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
      </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: For me everything looks fine, can you make a screenshot?

Comment: I added some images  to improve the comprehension of the problem.

Comment: This is a bug , see the related bug-report: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5713  The bug is active now for 8 month without a fix(when there would be  a solution I guess they already had fixed it)

Comment: There's a potential solution but we must use javascript 1- [Use Info Window](http://www.canbike.ca/information-technology/2013/11/01/firefox-infowindow-scrollbar-fix-google-maps-api-v3.html) 2- [Attach your info window with your polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111046/google-maps-attaching-infowindows-to-polygons-in-array)